# How to access a dataframe column with no name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

Here is the dataframe I am trying to access its columns (team and player)

```
                PSxG    GA  
league  season  game    team    player          
ITA-Serie A 2223    2022-08-14 Fiorentina-Cremonese Cremonese   Ionuț Radu  2.5 3   3ed8bdff
Fiorentina  Pierluigi Gollini   1.2 2   3ed8bdff
```

Here is the output of the columns function:

```
Index(['PSxG', 'GA', ''], dtype='object')
```

I also tried to use `iloc` in order to access the first row and get player and team

```
PSxG         2.5
GA             3
        3ed8bdff
Name: (ITA-Serie A, 2223, 2022-08-14 Fiorentina-Cremonese, Cremonese, Ionuț Radu), dtype: object
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. But you can use `iloc` to access any indices of a row or column. So for example if you just want the first column of data you can use `df.iloc[:,0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of .iloc, you can use .iat.

In the example you provided, the column number for team is 3 and for player is 4, so you can access the column elements like this as shown below.

for example

- you have **10** rows in your dataFrame
- name of your dataFrame is **data_table**

```
for i in range(10):
    print(data_table.iat[i,3])  # printing "team" column elements
    print(data_table.iat[i,4])  # printing "player" column elements
```

You can take a look at the documentation for more information.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html